# Get data to go through USB to Serial Port of Digi One SP Device

Tags: serial-port

**Basic problem:**
I bought a "Digi One SP" device to attempt to connect a USB input to a TCP output. The Digi One SP has 3 ports: power, ethernet, and DB9 serial (Image 1). It also has a "Digi One SP Configuration and Management" tool (Image 2). **The problem is that when I send data through the USB to the Gearmo Serial Port, that data doesn't reach the Digi Serial Port ("Total Data In" doesn't get updated)**. I don't know how to debug from here.

Using the loopback plug that came with the Digi device, I've verified that each side of the connection between Gearmo serial output and the Digi serial input works (including the gender changer). I can put the loopback on the Digi serial port and send data through Telnet, and see it bounce back to Telnet (in this case I see "Total Data In" updates in the Digi monitoring tool). Likewise, I can put the loopback on the Gearmo serial port and send data to the serial port and see it bounce back to the serial port. So somehow it is lost in the connection between these two ports.

**More details:**

- Sending data through the USB: I've tried various ways to do this. I'm currently using the Macbook program "Serial". I've also done it on the Windows VM using the program "Free Device Monitoring Studio".
- Sending data through ethernet: I'm using telnet on a Windows VM to monitor the TCP side and send data through that side for testing the loopback plug on the Digi device.
- Serial Port configuration: I've tried each of these, changing them in both the Digi management tool and on the computer.

Baud Rate: 9600, Data Bits: 8, Parity: None, Stop Bits: 1. Flow Control: None.

Baud Rate: 1200, Data Bits: 7, Parity: None, Stop Bits: 1. Flow Control: None.

**Image 1 - Hardware Setup**
[Digi One SP Hardware Setup](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9stom.png)

**Image 2 - Serial Port Diagnostics**
[Digi One SP Serial Port Diagnostics](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sP0Ar.png)
(Note: The reason there are 16 bytes of "Total Data In" in Image 2 is because this was one of my tests with the loopback plug in which I sent data through telnet and it bounced back into the serial port. I don't get any bytes when I send data through the USB to the serial port).

Comment: Instead of focusing on the Digi adapter (as in your title and descriptions), you need to clearly identify ***both*** devices that you are using.  *"So somehow it is lost in the connection between these two ports."* -- Instead of the gender-changer seen in your photo, you probably need to use a [null modem cable](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Null_modem).

Comment: Thank you for the comment. Do you think I should edit the title to something more like: "Get data to go through serial port connection between Gearmo USB-to-Serial-Cable to GenderChanger to Digi-One-SP?"

Comment: Also, regarding your advice, what is the reason a gender changer might not work vs. a null modem cable?

Comment: Also, I just tried it with this serial cable and no gender changer, and still don't see any data in. Is this the kind of cable your were thinking of https://www.amazon.com/DTECH-RS232-Serial-Straight-Through/dp/B07B2CBWVQ

Comment: Regarding my last question I actually see in the product description "this is a serial straight cable, DO NOT perform crossover (Null Modem) function."

Comment: Disregard my question about the difference between a gender changer and null modem cable as well. I think this is a good explanation: https://knowledge.ni.com/KnowledgeArticleDetails?id=kA00Z000000P9w0SAC

Comment: I tried the null modem cable and that did turn out to be the issue